# How do I select a item out of a radio button list?

Tags: vb.net

I have a radio button list set up for sorting with 2 possible choices. when the page loads i need to have one of those selected, however it has to be through code rather than manual section in the design screen.

Comment: do i use .selectedarguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first item selected:

```
myRbl.Items(0).Selected = True
```

Or the second:

```
myRbl.Items(1).Selected = True
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great, another question to follow up: how to i make the sorting happen immediately when a user changes from item0 to item1?

Comment: @TerribleCoder007 Create a separate question and post your current code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set their `Checked` flags to true/false.

```
rbFirstOne.Checked = True
rbSecondOne.Checked = False
```

Edit: Oh, radio button list, not just button. Sorry.